# how to access rails's session value in faye extensions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, faye

> how can I access session value in extensions? 
>   in that incoming and outgoing function.
>   I'm using faye+thin, and my these code is under my project/faye.ru

```
require 'faye'

Faye::WebSocket.load_adapter('thin')
bayeux = Faye::RackAdapter.new(:mount => '/faye', :timeout => 25)

bayeux.on(:handshake) do |client_id|
# event listener logic
puts client_id
end
bayeux.on(:publish) do |client_id, channel, data|
  # event listener logic
  puts data 
  puts channel
end

class ServerAuth  
  def incoming(message, request,callback)
    if message['channel'] !~ %r{^/meta/}  
      ***#I want to access rails's session here.***
      if message['ext'].nil? || message['ext']['auth_token'] == 'abc' 
       # message['error'] = 'Invalid authentication token.'
      end  
    end  
    callback.call(message)  
  end
  def outgoing(message, callback)
    if message['channel'] == '/message/admin'
        message['error'] = 'You can not subscribe this channel'
    end
    callback.call(message)
  end
end

bayeux.add_extension(ServerAuth.new);

run bayeux
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store a user session in Redis. For example, you can store CSRF token with user's id.

In faye.ru file, you can access to that Redis database with user sessions.
You can simply add faye extension with authentication logic.

```
require 'redis'
redis = Redis.new
class CsrfProtection
  def incoming(message, request, callback)
    message_token = message['ext'] && message['ext'].delete('csrfToken')
    user_id = redis.get(message_token)
    #Your auth logic
    callback.call(message)
  end
end
```

In browser client code you must add extension for sending CSRF token with each faye message.

```
var faye = new Faye.Client("http://localhost:9292/faye");
faye.addExtension({
    outgoing: function(message, callback) {
       message.ext = message.ext || {};
       message.ext.csrfToken = $("meta[name=csrf-token]").attr("content");
         return callback(message);
    }
});
```

Hope this helped you